# logging and performance analysis

Tags: performance, logging

When I enable logging for an application, at the same time when I am doing performance measurement on the application, then the logging will degrade the performance considerably on some systems. Is there any way this can be prevented? so that logging does not prevent the performance.

Comment: Performance mesurement may decrease performances if you also mesure logging performances. Usually, you have to disable some parts of the application from the Performance Mesurement tool. Logging is one of them.

Comment: Which programming/logging/performance-mesurement-system are you using? May be your performance-mesurement-system has a function to exclute certain modules/dlls/jars from the time-spent-in-function-report. The more specific you question the more specific is the answer you will get.

Comment: I am going to use log4j for logging and perf4j along with my own appenders to measure various performance metric. But when logging is enabled in production, it may increase or decrease the performance depending on the application. So is there any way both can be prevented from affecting each other. I dont this disabling logging would solve the issue or performance not measuring the logging. As logging will use certain amount of resources which will reflect in the performance metrics like memory use, over all time delay etc.